# Trying to use sumifs in excel to sum previous rows in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I'm trying to use sumifs with indirect and address to sum all of the previous rows in a column, however, I receive a #value error when I attempt. I was wondering if someone could help point out the error in my formula or process? Here is the formula I'm using:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,[Value])&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,[Value])),[Category],"s",[Type],2)
```

[image]

If you look at the dataset it also seems like the sumif_test is malfunctioning and summing the whole column instead of the specified range.

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Does this work? `=SUMIFS(Table1[[#Headers],[value]]:[@value], Table1[[#Headers],[category]]:[@category], "s", Table1[[#Headers],[type]]:[@type], 2)`

Comment: This is working on the sample data but when I try to apply it to the actual dataset I get an error that the syntax of the name isn't correct and it highlights [@value]; I can fix it by changing all of the [@]s to [@[]]s (eg; [@[Value]] but then it gives a value of 0 no matter what.

Comment: Ahhh looks like sumifs can't use OR() arguments, only AND(). My formula had an OR() in the sumifs so I wrapped the sumifs in a SUM() and changed the removed the OR(), wrapping the arguments in {}. Eg; Sumifs(OR(a,s)) became Sum(Sumifs({a,s}))

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm sorry, I'm new to the site and not sure how to designate your answers as helpful or give credit.

Comment: Now that we've got the problems worked out, I've created an answer below which can be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an OR condition, wrap the SUMIFS in a SUM.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Table1[[#Headers],[value]]:[@value], Table1[[#Headers],[category]]:[@category], {"a", "s"}, Table1[[#Headers],[type]]:[@type], 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below, I use this to SUM running totals (or all previous ROWS), not sure if it will transfer to a `SUMIFS`.

I have assumed Value is in Column A and starts Row 1, adjust the formula if this is not the case.

```
=SUMIFS($A$2:A2,[Category],"s",[Type],2)
```

OR

```
=SUMIFS($A$2:A2,$B$2:B2,"s",$C$2:C2,2)
```

This allows the SUM range to always start at row 2, and only extend to your current ROW.

Let me know if this doesn't work and I will remove it as an answer.

Comment: The first will not work as the ranges will not be the same size.  The second should work.

Comment: The second one is working but I need to use the table headers as references.